# Destroying an enemy animation after it has been hit

Tags: java, animation, lwjgl, slick2d, game-development

I'm trying to destroy an enemy animation after it has been hit by the a bullet... The way I have it set up now is that,
if the bullet animation hits any position on the enemy ship, give that animation a new empty animation and then draw the empty animation on the screen.  The problem is that now every time the ship get's hit the game crashes... The code below is from my update method.  What am I doing wrong? Can somebody please help me

```
            //ENEMYSHIP DESTRUCTION 
            if((shootPosX>enemy1PosX -25 && shootPosX <enemy1PosX + 25)&&  (shootPosY>enemy1PosY - 40 && shootPosY< enemy1PosY + 40)) {
            enemy1 = new Animation ();
            enemy1.draw();
        }
```

please let me know if you need any more information...

Answer (score 0):

It would be more convenient to either a) Keep the animation in memory (don't cast it to new blank animation) and simply don't render it when its owner is dead so that maybe at some later time (like a restart or something similar) you can reuse it or b) Delete the animation from whatever container you are using for you animations (list, array, map).

I recommend the first one, something along this.

```
public class Enemy {

public enum State {
    DEAD, ALIVE
}

private State state;

// ...
// stuff

public State getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(State state) {
    this.state = state;
}

}
```

Logic/Rendering

```
 if (enemy gets shot) {
 //You want him dead on one shot
 //If using intenger
  enemy.setState(State.DEAD)
}


//Stuff


//Rendering

for (Enemy e: somecontainerforenemy){
 if(e.getState()==State.DEAD){
  continue;
  e.draw()
}
}
```

Option **b**:

```
if(enemy gets shot){
 enemycontainer.remove(enemy)
}
```

Then he simply won't get rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If it is all in the same class, why don't you just set up a simple boolean to control whether or not the ship should be drawn?

```
//ENEMYSHIP DESTRUCTION 
        if((shootPosX>enemy1PosX -25 && shootPosX <enemy1PosX + 25)&&  (shootPosY>enemy1PosY - 40 && shootPosY< enemy1PosY + 40)) {
        shipDraw == false;
    }
```

Then within your ship Draw() method,

```
if(shipDraw){
   //your code
 }

else{
 //dont draw the ship or do ship explosion animation then end
}
```

But if its not in the same class, try not to reference the boolean statically

Comment: I tried what you said and now the problem is that the ship goes away but only for the split second when the bullet hits the ship... After that I comes right back

Comment: @iibinxx It could either be the fact that your onDraw() method is redrawing the ship through some other means and you need to catch it and tell it not to draw once shipDraw == false or shipDraw is being assigned true again somehow? How have you declared it?